# Can inline-block elements be justified aligned over multiple lines

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, text-justify

I have many varied cases where I would like a DIV containing an `inline-block` menu element - typically an anchor - to act as if vertically justifying the elements, when an element overflows on to multiple lines.

I will use one example case to explain what I would like to achieve:

See my codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBRpqJ?editors=110

Output:
[image: Image 1 - 100% width]

What happens is that if the browser resizes to a smaller size, then the final `inline-block` Anchor element falls down onto a new line, see screenshot (at width ~725px):

Output:
[image: image 2 - 725px width]

That's fine, in itself, but what I would like it to do is to split the elements within the DIV equally, as it's on two lines, to then be *equally* dispersed over two lines and therefore be roughly justified, If you resize the codepen to approximately 500px wide you will see how I'd like it to look *if the elements can not all stay on one line*. So the image below would be would I would like to see if any line breaking occurs within the parent DIV element.

Output:

[image: image 3 - desired layout format]

I realise that the term *equally* is an exact term for an inexact situation but to justify the elements in a block so that each row in the block has the same number of elements +/- 1 (for odd counts).

**Is this something that can be done with CSS?**

P.S> The contents of these elements are dynamic and varied and the situations any solution would be useful for would also be dynamic and varied so solutions *specifically for this case* will probably not help.

Edit:
Flexbox has been suggested as a solution, how would I use Flexbox to achieve the desired result?

Edit 2:
Criteria -- The elements in the menu are centre aligned and are each separate `inline-block`s . Justifying them all it does is screw up the centre alignment and add extra spacer lines around the Anchor elements in the NAV container.

Edit 3:
I will put my code here, used on the codepen example:

CSS:

```
.mainbox {
        width:90%;
        max-width:1200px;
        min-width:400px;
        margin:0.4em auto;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 1em;
        border: 1px solid #006;
    }

nav {
    background-color: rgba(204,204,204,0.4);
    padding:5px 5px 0px 5px;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    /* bottom increased from zero to make example clearer on codepen */
  bottom:1em;
    margin:auto;
    width:90%; 
  /* width adjusted from 100% for codepen layout */
}
nav a {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding:2px 4px;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    line-height: 1.1em;
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    margin:0 3px 3px 3px;
    display:inline-block;
}
nav a:hover, nav a:focus {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color:#000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="mainbox">
  <header>
  <nav>
           <a href="#cal" title="Cottage Availbility">Availability</a>
<a href="#tariff" title="Tariff">Tariff</a>
<a href="#" title="Make A Booking ">Make A Booking</a>
<a href="http://www.website.com/AccessStatement.pdf" title="Access Statement" target="_blank">Access Statement</a>
<a href="http://www.website.com/TandCs.pdf" title="T&amp;Cs" target="_blank">T&amp;Cs</a>
<a href="#contact" title="Contact the owners">Contact</a>
<a href="http://www.elsewhere.co.uk" title="Visit the website">
Parent Site</a>
        </nav>
  </header>
  </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried flexbox?

Comment: Is flexbox fairly straightforward to implement? No, I've not heard of flex box :-(

Comment: I've only used it once to try it out and it can be a bit tricky at first but from what I've seen on complete examples you can do exactly what you're looking for with it.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz I am reading about flexbox, it is additional rules for CSS? I was about to ask for an example to get started but see your second comment

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `:after` pseudo element hack. Basically it works like you're justifying text. In order to get the last line to justify, you have to force a fake line using `:after` to get the browser to justify the last line. Just think about how justify works, it never justifies the last line.

```css
.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin:10px;
}
ul:after {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Item 12341231</li>
  <li>Item 123462346</li>
  <li>Item 234523</li>
  <li>Item 34563457</li>
  <li>Item 456756</li>
  <li>Item 567856</li>  
  <li>Item 678969</li>
  <li>Item 7453456</li>
  <li>Item 8234523</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry Jeff, this solution doesn't work for me, it adds spacing around the  elements within the container and does not *vertically* justify them.

Answer (score 1):

One trick might be to use media queries:

```
@media (max-width: 725px) {
    .parent-div {
        width: 500px;
    }
}
```

Not perfect, but setting these will wrap everything just the way you want it.

Comment: I have tried this approach the thing is there is a shading background on the menu that would need to stay in place so I would need to put a DIV in the NAV. media queries and manual adjustments are an option but I was looking for a more elegant solution. Thanks though.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz's recommendation above might be the more elegant approach. I haven't delved too deep into flexbox myself. Good luck!

Comment: I would like to learn more about flexbox, it may be the solution. Cheers Beautifulcoder.

Answer (score 1):

This workaround is also based on @media, but using a pseudo element to make line break.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
    nav span:nth-of-type(4)::after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        height: 10px;
    }
}
```

**Note:** I added a `<span>` tag around each `<a>` in order to make it happen.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/s88381hb/1/

Comment: cheers, does it have to apply to an inline element, hence has to be a span rather than the anchors?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to do this but you can use javascript to enforce the CSS whichmight be more beneficial

Comment: Can you give any guide to how javascript could help here?